# How to use Stored Procedures w/ ASP.NET DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, ado

Question can also be:

*What is your preferred way of invoking stored procedures to fill a DataGrid?*

I am currently developing an ASP.NET Page, and I would like to know if Linq is the right way to go for use with my SQL Server DB.

ADO seems nice too, so I would just like to have feedback on what is the most appropriate in general terms..

LINQ sure makes it easy to call a stored procedure, but I am kind of stuck in trying to find out the right way to put the result set from the stored procedure to a datagrid.

> Don't think I want to do a foreach
>   there..but all examples seem to point that way.. or I'm just confused

[I have read this blog post](http://blogs.interfacett.com/dan-wahlins-blog/2008/2/17/linq-and-lambdas-and-sprocsoh-my.html), and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546186.aspx), it seems the ways to go are foreach and Ienumerable methods.. and I am a bit confused about the whole thing.

I am also thinking about the [tutorial for creating a Movie DataBase](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-21-cs.aspx) where the DataGrid simply became unnecessary in that case.

> What is the simplest, most to the
>   point way of accessing a simple SQL
>   Procedure and returning a populated datagrid, or datagrid like data presentation model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using Linq to SQL. You are correct in thinking that you should not be using any foreach loops - all you need is databinding.

eg. In your code behind, you might have a DataBind event that does something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBanding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            // Get an instance of our generated DataContext class.
            DAL.AdventureWorks db =
                new DAL.AdventureWorks(
                    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorksCS"].ConnectionString);

            // Get a strongly typed List from the Stored Procedure output
            List<DAL.MySPResult> myData = db.MySP().ToList();

            GridView1.DataSource = myData;
}
```

You will need to have setup your Stored Procedure in your Linq to SQL Classes by dragging it onto the design surface.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! My main problem was that I wasnt including Linq..so the Option for List() wasn't in the Intelisense... Thanks, its all good now.

Answer (score 1):

Using a SqlDataSource is the most straightforward way.  If you are isolating all of your DB calls in a business layer then you could simply create an ObjectDataSource that called the stored procedure. While it may feel like overkill here, this is a useful skill and *very* easy to implement once you get the hang of it.

You really don't need LINQ or a foreach, etc. if you'll be using a data-bound control since you won't need to fill it manually (this is what data binding is all about).

One more thing - I would **strongly** recommend that you use a *GridView* rather than the DataGrid; it is newer, has many more features automated, and is a more capable and attractive control.  Let me know if you need any sample code.